# CPP error in overloading new operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

The Following Code I took from Let us C++ - Yeswant kanetkar. I am new to CPP and i am getting the following errors while overloading new operator.

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]|
error: initializing argument 2 of 'void* operator new [](std::size_t, void*)' [-fpermissive]|
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]|
error: initializing argument 2 of 'void* operator new [](std::size_t, void*)' [-fpermissive]|
```

The program is as follows :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <new>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void memwarning();
    void *operator new(size_t,int);
    void operator delete(void *);

    char *p = new('$') char[100];
    cout<<endl<<"First Allocation : p = "<<hex<<long(p)<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    cout << p[i];

    delete p;

    p = new('*')char[64000u];
    delete p;

    return 0;
}

void memwarning()
{
    cout <<endl<<"Free Store has now gone empty";
    exit(1);
}

void * operator new(size_t sz, int setvalue)
{
    void *p;

    p = malloc(sz);
        if(p==NULL)
    memwarning();

    memset(p,setvalue,sz);
    return (p);
}

void operator delete(void *pp)
{
    free(pp);
}
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: `What is the reason for this error?` Because - `Yeswant kanetkar`'s books are non-standard.

Comment: Can you resolve the issue and suggest me some good books

Comment: Go to [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2b%2b?sort=frequent&pageSize=15)

Answer (score -1):

When you allocate an array, you are calling new[], and when you delete an array you should use delete[]. These are different operators than new and delete. Fixing this causes this to compile:

```
int main() 
{
    void memwarning();
    void *operator new(size_t,int);
    void operator delete(void *);
    char *p = new('$') char;
    cout<<endl<<"First Allocation : p = "<<hex<<long(p)<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        cout << p[i];

    delete p;

    p = new('*')char;
    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```